# ASP SQL Update Page Views on Link Clicks

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, search, pageviews

I have a website that currently has a search form written is ASP. The search calls my SQL Database and puts the results into a table with clickable images to HTML pages for each search result. Currently I am sorting the results by an field in my SQL table. The code for each search result is like this:

```
<a href="/model-homes/<%# DataSet1.FieldValue("address", Container) %>/index.html"><img src="/model-homes/<%# DataSet1.FieldValue("address", Container) %>/plan-1st-floor.jpg" width="400" border=0/></a>
```

What I would like to do is once the link is clicked it sends an update to the SQL Database and adds +1 to the view count. This way I can change my sort to the view count and get the most popular links at the top of the search results. The primary key for the SQL Database is the "address" field if that helps to increment the view count.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I seem to be at the limit of my programming knowledge.

-- Update #1 --

So I am trying to work through this. Can I add the code for updating the SQL Database right into the link like this? It does not seem to be working.

```
<a href="/model-homes/<%# DataSet1.FieldValue("address", Container) %>/index.html" onclick="UPDATE dbo.main SET pageview=pageview+1 WHERE address=<%# DataSet1.FieldValue("address", Container) %>"><img src="/model-homes/<%# DataSet1.FieldValue("address", Container) %>/plan-1st-floor.jpg" width="400" border=0/></a>
```

I am not sure if I have to call it another way. I am trying.

-- Update #2 --

So I tried changing the code again in order to figure this out. So now I am trying to pass this through a function because I do not think that it will work within the hyperlink. So this is what I did:

```
<a
    href="model-homes/<%# DataSet1.FieldValue("address", Container) %>/index.html"
    onclick="UpdateDB(<%# DataSet1.FieldValue("address", Container) %>)"
>
<img
    src="model-homes/<%# DataSet1.FieldValue("address", Container) %>/plan-1st-floor.jpg"
    width="400"
    border=0
/>
</a>
```

And this is the function:

```
function UpdateDb(@address)
{
    SELECT pageview FROM dbo.main WHERE address=@address
    UPDATE pageview=pageview+1  FROM dbo.main  WHERE address=@address
}
```

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just finished with day 2 of trying to figure this thing out. Looking for any approach that might help.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you're trying can be successful if you can change index.html to index.aspx to solve this problem:

1. Using query string variable but it is based on the assumption that index.html can be changed to index.aspx:

   ```
   <a href="/model-homes/<%# DataSet1.FieldValue("address", Container) html"       
       <img src="/model-homes/<%# DataSet1.FieldValue("address", Container) %>
           /plan-1st-floor.jpg" width="400" border=0/>
   </a>
   ```

   Add query string variables at the end of index.html, like mentioned below:

   ```
   <a href="/model-homes/<%# DataSet1.FieldValue("address", Container)%>
       /index.aspx?name=<%# DataSet1.FieldValue("address", Container) %>"       
       <img src="/model-homes/<%# DataSet1.FieldValue("address", Container) %>
           /plan-1st-floor.jpg" width="400" border=0/>
   </a>
   ```
2. If index.html cannot be changed to index.aspx then create intermediary page to move from `index.html?name=<%# DataSet1.FieldValue("address", Container) %>` to `newpage.aspx`, do the processing of updating to the database on pageload function, and then redirect back to index.html.